How to write an inequality?
I have a very simple doubt regarding the writing of inequalities.
Consider any arbitrary finite set $X$ and three functions $f,g,h:X\to\mathbb{R}$. Fix any element $x\in X$ and suppose the following inequality holds:
\begin{gather}
f(x)>g(x)+h(x)
\end{gather}
Now, consider some element $x’\in X\backslash\{x\}$ and suppose the following equality holds:
\begin{gather}
g(x)+h(x)=g(x’)+h(x’)
\end{gather}
Then, is the following expression correct?
\begin{align}
f(x)&>g(x)+h(x)\\
&>g(x’)+h(x’)
\end{align}
Alternatively, what I am asking is whether the second line of the last math expression reads as
\begin{gather}
f(x)>g(x’)+h(x’)
\end{gather}
or as
\begin{gather}
g(x)+h(x)>g(x’)+h(x’)
\end{gather}
If the second line of my expression reads as $f(x)>g(x’)+h(x’)$, then it is correct; but if it reads as $g(x)+h(x)>g(x’)+h(x’)$, then it is not.

If $A > B$ and $B=C$ then $A > C$, but not $B > C$.


Then, is the following expression correct?
\begin{align}
f(x)&>g(x)+h(x)\\
&>g(x’)+h(x’)
\end{align}
Alternatively, what I am asking is whether the second line of the last math expression reads as
\begin{gather}
f(x)>g(x’)+h(x’)
\end{gather}
or as
\begin{gather}
g(x)+h(x)>g(x’)+h(x’)
\end{gather}

It reads as the second. I would format your desired expression as
\begin{align}
f(x)&>g(x)+h(x)\\
&=g(x’)+h(x’)
\end{align}
The idea is that
\begin{align}
f(x)&>g(x)+h(x)\\
&=g(x’)+h(x’)
\end{align}
is just a multi-line version of
$$
f(x) > g(x) + h(x) = g(x') + h(x')
$$
done on multiple lines for aesthetic concerns.
